# String convert to Json Array and then parse value in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to the swift language. I am trying to fetching some data from an API call and response to that API is "{"status":1,"msg":"Please enter Mobile number"}"

I have the above response in a string How can I convert this string to JSONObject and then parse it and get status value?

I am an android developer we have evaluate expression while debugging code is there some like in Xcode so I can execute some code run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use `SwiftyJson` library . 
first create a model from your json using `http://jsoncafe.com`

you can parse data and model it using the following code

```
 let json = JSON(response)
 let message = Message(fromJson: json )
```

then you have access to your variable => `message.status`

Comment: I am using SwiftyJson can you please help me what should I selected in Code Template in http://jsoncafe.com

Comment: @sofquestion9 If you are new to swift it makes even more sense to use the built in support for json rather than some 3rd party library. Specially since this built-in support is much better. So my suggestion is that you look at the other answers posted that uses Codable or JSONSerialization

Comment: @ArvinRezaei Thanks your code is runnable but not returning corrected output. let jsonTag = JSON(tag)
        let message = loginModelRootClass(fromJson: jsonTag )
        
        print(message.msg ?? 4)

Comment: it is getting return from here 
if json.isEmpty{
            return
        }

Comment: confirm that your response is json , try  json["msg"].stringValue

Comment: It is always printing 4

let json = """
        {"status":1,"msg":"Please enter Mobile number"}
        """
        let jsonTag = JSON(json)
        let loginModelRootClass = LoginModelRootClass(fromJson: jsonTag )
        
        print(loginModelRootClass.status ?? 4)

Comment: where to try json["msg"].stringValue?

Comment: Thanks, I had figure out myself

Answer (score 0):

`JSONSerialization` is the tool you are looking for. It handles converting JSON into objects, and objects into JSON. If you receive a JSON string represented as `Data`, you can pass it into `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)`

If you are wanting to convert `Data` into an object:

```swift
//Where 'data' is the data received from the API call
guard let jsonObject = try? (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]) else {
    return
}
let status = jsonObject["status"] as! Int
let message = jsonObject["msg"] as! String
```

If you are wanting to convert `String` into an object:

```swift
//Where 'string' is the JSON as a String
guard let jsonObject = try? (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: string.data(using: .utf8), options: []) as! [String:Any]) else {
    return
}
let status = jsonObject["status"] as! Int
let message = jsonObject["msg"] as! String
```

**Source:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization