# Remove unwanted data from JSON using swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am getting response

```
{"msg":"Success: Mobile Number is Valid","status":0}396b6c706a54383638343131
```

How can I get valid JSON from my API response using swift I am getting JSON error.

Code:

```
NSLog("Login response: " + response, "response")
    let jsonTag = JSON(response.dropLast(24).data(using: .utf8)!)
    let loginModelRootClass = LoginModelRootClass(fromJson: jsonTag )

    if  (loginModelRootClass.status == 0)
    {
        /* successfully login */
        NSLog("Login response: " + loginModelRootClass.msg, "response")
    }
    else
    {
        /* failure login */
        NSLog("Login response: " + loginModelRootClass.msg, "response")
```

New to swift please help.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: @Zun added code please check

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813972/string-convert-to-json-array-and-then-parse-value-in-swift-ios?

Comment: You should not fix anything like this on client. Ask backend to fix the issue by returning a valid JSON.

Comment: you json not valid anymore

Comment: Why do you have garbage at the end?  It's valid UTF8, and means "9klpjT868411". Is it always the same? How did you get `response`?

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the comments that the best option is to get the backend to send valid json.  However if that is not possible, you could use the function below to remove the invalid trailing data and then decode with `Codable`

```
func clean(json: String) -> String? {
   guard let closing = json.lastIndex(of: "}") else {return nil}
   var string = json
   let range = string.index(after: closing)..<string.endIndex
   string.removeSubrange(range)
   return string
}
```