# iOS swift - convert JSON string to array and parse each item

Tags: ios, swift

So far I have this:

```
do{
    let (responseString, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

    if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: responseString){
        quotes = decodedResponse
    }
}catch{
    print("data not valid")
}
```

which instantly converts the json string to object array (`quotes`) but this is not what I need.

I need to parse each item and then add it to the object array like this:

```
quotes.append(Quote(quote_id: id, quote: qqq, author: aut, series: srs))
```

how to do that?

The only similar question I've found is

[String convert to Json Array and then parse value in swift iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813972/string-convert-to-json-array-and-then-parse-value-in-swift-ios)

but he doesn't have a json array but json object so the answers there aren't helping

Comment: What does your json look like?  What would be the difference between what Codable is doing for you and what you say you want to do?

Comment: Like this: [{"quote_id":1,"quote":"I am not in danger, Skyler. I am the danger!","author":"Walter White","series":"Breaking Bad"},{"quote_id":2,"quote":"Stay out of my territory.","author":"Walter White","series":"Breaking Bad"},{"quote_id":3,"quote":"IFT","author":"Skyler White","series":"Breaking Bad"},{"quote_id":4,"quote":"I watched Jane die. I was there. And I watched her die. I watched her overdose and choke to death. I could have saved her. But I didn’t.","author":"Walter White","series":"Breaking Bad"}]

Comment: The difference is I need to be able to make more requests without completely overwriting quotes but append new stuff and I also need to change the values in if else etc

Comment: You can either iterate over the `quotes` array that `JSONDecoder` is giving you and do whatever work is required with each element or you can add custom decoding code to the `Quote` struct.  I would probably do the first one

Comment: The first one is what I will do in case there isn't a way to do this how I'm asking which is the way you can do it in Android + Kotlin. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: There are any number of ways to parse JSON.  By far the simplest in Swift is to use `Decodable` and `JSONDecoder`, which is what you are doing.  You can use the older techniques from the question you linked to or you can read up on the `Decodable` protocol and implementing a custom decoding strategy.  The code you write is going to be dictated on what you do with the `data` you get from the response.  You could write your own JSON parser if you wanted....

Comment: Working on the JSON string will gives you a lot of work. You can do it with regex, and replace/add text inside. But as it is json string, it is easier and more secure to convert to an array where you can add/suppress/replace object and then convert it back to json string.